# float content to two colomns in one div

Tags: css, html

I need the content to flow in two coloumns and I dont have the control over the inner div. Can I write CSS such that the content goes in two colomns. I can write CSS only for the outer div.

```
<div style="">first Colomun Content
            <div>Second Coloumn Content
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give a sample picture of what do you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can you only write CSS for the outer div?

You can do: `div > div { border:1px red dotted;}` to style the inner div. And what do you mean  by 2 columns? Can you give an example?

Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/eNwEZ/

Comment: It's CSS 2, From what I remember it works from IE7+. But you don't need to use it. See: http://jsfiddle.net/eNwEZ/6/

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one div in your outside div you can give it an id and after in the css give the inside div the property but by using the main id.

Look at the example here it is easier to show than explain..:)

http://jsfiddle.net/etienne_carre/UAgbw/